# Update solr index from mvc application

Tags: model-view-controller, solr

Is there a way to update an solr index with documents och delete documents from for example mvc application?

Like this:

1. User update a post in the database in a mvc application
2. A call is made with the new information, that is sending the new post (with for example json) to solr to update the index.

Or do one have to use the commandline to trigger solr to update the index based on updated field since last indexation.

I havent found anything about this in the documentation, but i dont see why this should not work.

Or maybe this is a bad idea to make updates like this and its better to have a routine that is run every night that update the index from Changes in the database?
But then Changes in database is not reflected in the index until hours later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store new information (documents) and update existing one without using "the command line"... The strategy you should follow will depend on your system, but normally adding/updating your index could be done at any time, and most probably if new information is available (e.g.: new post) it probably is wise to make it available as soon as possible...

---

References/Examples:

- partial update document example: http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/
- In Java applications, using SolrJ (java client) the `StreamingUpdateSolrServer` can be used to update existing documents

Comment: How is that done?

Is there an url to witch one can send for example json?

Comment: Hi @david2342 I have updated my answer with some examples that may give you some guidance to further learn about update.